# How to construct a Path from a jar:file URL?

Tags: java, jar, uri

How do I construct a `Path` to a `jar:file` URL?

Invoking `Paths.get(new URI("jar:file:/C:/foo.jar!/bar.html"))` throws `FileSystemNotFoundException` (notice the file system is missing, not the file itself).

As far as I can tell, both files exist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Paths` tries to resolve a `FileSystem` which would contain your `Path`. (Actually this may be an implementation detail. The spec simply states that it will check the default `FileSystem`.) If you haven't registered/created such a `FileSystem`, it won't be able to find it.

You would create a new `FileSystem` from the jar file and access the entry `Path` through that `FileSystem`.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/foo.jar");
URI uri = new URI("jar", path.toUri().toString(),  null);

Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
env.put("create", "true");

FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
Path file = fileSystem.getPath("bar.html");
System.out.println(file);
```

You could then use

```
Paths.get(new URI("jar:file:/C:/foo.jar!/bar.html"))
```

Be careful to properly close the `FileSystem` when finished using it.

For more information about ZipFileSystemProvider, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html).

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 7, Java allows us to have FileSystems, not only open a file on the local directory, but to also define our own File System. There are many uses for it, such as having a distributed file system, being able to use compression, have an http bridge, so many things...

In your case, what you need is a way to read a jar. Well, since a jar is just a zipped file, you can use the FileSystem with the default. It doesn't get any easier than that:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Throwable {
        String jarName = "/Users/asantos/.m2/repository/ant/ant/1.6/ant-1.6.jar";
        String fileInside = "/META-INF/LICENSE.txt";

        Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>(); 

        URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:"+jarName);

        try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {

            System.out.println(new String(Files.readAllBytes(zipfs.getPath(fileInside))));

        } 
    }
}
```

I shamelessly copied my code from the documentation, adapting for a jar instead of a zip file: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html

Comment: This is available starting from Java 7, not 8

Comment: I didn't say only Java 8 had it. I just stated the one I am used to, but I'll update my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.*;

public static void method() {
    Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
    // here false is used to indicate the zip file system provider not to create a new zip/jar file if it does not exist.
    env.put("create", Boolean.FALSE.toString());
    Path jarFilePath = Paths.get("C:\\test_jar_parent", "myjarfile.jar");
    String uriPath = "jar:" + jarFilePath.toUri().toString();
    URI uri = URI.create(uriPath);
    try (FileSystem jarFs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env, null)) {
        ...
    }
}
```